# How to send xml post params with the help of node.js

Tags: xml, node.js, post, http-post

Trying to post XML data to following url via node js:-

```
var request = require("request");
var utf8 = require('utf8');



var abc = '<ENVELOPE><HEADER><TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST></HEADER><BODY><EXPORTDATA><REQUESTDESC><REPORTNAME>Stock Summary</REPORTNAME><STATICVARIABLES><EXPLODEFLAG>Yes</EXPLODEFLAG><SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT><ACCOUNTTYPE>All Inventory Masters</ACCOUNTTYPE></STATICVARIABLES></REQUESTDESC></EXPORTDATA></BODY></ENVELOPE>';

request.post({
    url:"http://192.168.1.148",
    port: 9000,
    method:"POST",
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
    },
     body: abc
},
function(error, response, body){
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    console.log(body);
    console.log(error);
});
```

But interpreter is showing following error:-

> ```
> console.log(response.statusCode);
>                     ^
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
> at Request._callback (C:\Users\bliscar\prog10.js:18:25)
> at self.callback (C:\Users\bliscar\node_modules\request\request.js:198:22)
> at Request.emit (events.js:107:17)
> at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\bliscar\node_modules\request\request.js:
> ```
>
> 861:8)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:107:17)
>       at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:271:9)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
>       at net.js:459:14
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

Not able to work out what's the issue. Please help to resolve.

Comment: "But interpreter is showing some error." — Have you considered telling us what that error might be?

Comment: @Quentin : Added the error, Can you please help me out with the issue as it's pretty urgent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this :-

```
    var request = require("request");
var utf8 = require('utf8');



var abc = '<ENVELOPE>
          <HEADER>
                    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
                    <STATUS>1</STATUS>
          </HEADER>
</ENVELOPE><ENVELOPE><HEADER><TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST></HEADER><BODY><EXPORTDATA><REQUESTDESC><REPORTNAME>Stock Summary</REPORTNAME><STATICVARIABLES><EXPLODEFLAG>Yes</EXPLODEFLAG><SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT><ACCOUNTTYPE>All Inventory Masters</ACCOUNTTYPE></STATICVARIABLES></REQUESTDESC></EXPORTDATA></BODY></ENVELOPE>';

request.post({
    url:"http://192.168.1.148",
    port: 9000,
    method:"POST",
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
    },
     body: abc
},
function(error, response, body){
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    console.log(body);
    console.log(error);
});
```

Basically add versioning of tally in your xml. It won't show any error and xml will be synced

Comment: i I like this code. Quick question. What does this "var utf8 = require('utf8');" do?

Answer (score 0):

response is udnefined. 
This usualy happens when the server did not respond to the request.